# Repeating Method For Game

Tags: java, loops, methods

I am trying to create a game of two players where both players' turns are in methods and I want to repeat each method 4 times. I can't figure out how to loop the method in the main method. I have commented where to add the loop so if some can tell me how to loop that would be great. This is not my code but I have simplified it so that it is easy to follow. Thanks!

```
public static void Player1() {

        int total, num1, num2;
           total = num1 + num2;
       System.out.println(total);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //loop for method should go here
        }}
```

Comment: Please format your code so it's readable.

Comment: Have you just never written a loop? If so this question should be downvoted for no basic research. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm reading too much into things, but this looks like a homework assignment.  As such, I will try to be helpful without giving the answer away.

More than likely, you are looking for a [for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).  This is most commonly used when you have an iteration variable to keep track of which iteration the program is at but you don't need that information outside of the loop and when the loop has a simple mechanism to update the program's state to prepare for the next iteration.  This link also describes the *enhanced for loop* for iterating over collections.

Other looping mechanisms are the [while and do-while loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html). The while loops is probably the most commonly used looping mechanism because of its simple syntax (which, ironically, is why it's used when the iteration logic is more complicated).

On a side note, you instantiate an instance of Random in a function.  If I am understanding your explanation correctly, this function is supposed to be called when it is player one's turn.  That means you create a new pseudo-random number generator every time it is player one's turn.  If this function is called fast enough twice in a row, the second Random instance will be seeded with the same time value as the first, and will generate the exact same numbers.  It is far better to store this instance in a private static variable.

Comment: Thanks and I know the different loops but I don't know how to specifically loop this method so it can repeat six times.

Comment: I'd recommend talking to your teacher, but here's a very rough explanation.  In a loop, you describe how you want to control the repetition (the condition and, in the case of the for loop, initialization and incrementation as well) and the code you want to repeat (the body).  The statement's body is the same concept as a method's body; it will only execute when you want it to do so and as many times as you want it to do so.  So if you want to call your method six times, make a loop that runs six times and calls your method in its body.

Comment: Thanks and so I tried the following but it only repeated my loop twice and I don't why as i set the condition to equal 6.                        do 
         Player1();
        while (Player1() == 6);

Comment: Like I said, you're looking for a for loop.  Read the article I linked; it shows an example of how to loop ten times.  That is very easily changed to loop six times.  Besides, your function returns void, or nothing; it says nothing about how many times it has been called (and it probably shouldn't).

Comment: Sorry but I can't see the link you attached

Comment: So I tried this but it only executes the method once. Is there anything I should correct? *Player1() is the method               for (int k = Player1(); k == 4; k++) {
        System.out.print(k);
       }

Comment: I have also modified my code so you can see what I mean and provide an exact code? Thanks

Comment: I am surprised your code runs at all.  Player1 is a void function; by definition it cannot return anything.  int k = Player1(); should not compile.  This part of the for loop, the initialization, only executes once.  You want your method call in the body.  And, no, I'm not going to give you exact code because I've pointed out this is a homework assignment (which means giving you exact code would be cheating), and you did not deny it.  The point of programming assignments is to figure it out for yourself.